# Как создать копию списка, при этом чтоб 1 не изменялся при изменении другого

Tags: python, list, список

Очень нужна ваша помочь, потратил уйму времени. Не могу понять как сделать копию списка, чтоб 1 не зависел от 2

```
    field = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
    n = 2
    newfield = field[:]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            newfield[j][i] = field[i][j]
    print(newfield)
```

Это транспонирование двумерного списка. 
Когда изменяю 1 список `(newfield)`. второй  список `(field)` меняется сам вместе в `newfield`.
 Как это предотвратить????

Нужен ответ: `[[1,3],[2,4]]`, а получаю `[[1,2], [2,4]]`

Необходимо реализовать без применения функции `deepcopy()`

Comment: `newfield = list(field[:])` так передастся не ссылка, а значение

Comment: `newfield = [e[:] for e in field]`, `newfield = [e.copy() for e in field]`.

Comment: Геннадий, все равно не робит

Comment: А вот Михаил красавчик

Comment: Спасибо большое. Отправил бы как решение, поставил бы галочку.

Comment: @Ахмед Да, извиняюсь, не учел что у вас массив в массиве.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Все впорядке

Comment: Если задача именно в выполнении операции транспонирования, то в питоне для этого есть элегантный способ через `zip`.

Comment: @mkkik верю, но смысл задачи в том, чтобы сделать вручную, это больше как для обучения, нежели использования на практике.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда Вы пишете `newfield = field[:]`, то  Вы получаете новый список, но его элементы ссылаются на те же списки, что и элементы исходного `field`. Предлагаю несколько вариантов решения проблемы:

```py
newfield = [e[:] for e in field]  # Список копий подсписка field
```

```py
newfield = [e.copy() for e in field]  # Более читаемая версия предыдущего варианта
```

```py
newfield = list(map(list, field))  # В функциональном стиле
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import copy
>>> l = [[0], [1]]
>>> l1 = copy.deepcopy(l)
>>> l[0][0] = None
>>> print(l, l1, sep='\n')
[[None], [1]]
[[0], [1]]
```